# Xamarin Portable Comments Stacklayout height problems Listview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am having trouble with height problems in Xamarin PCL with Listview. I want to create a comments section in a scrollable page. But i am struggling with the height of the comments. It just wont expand.

Row.Definition = Auto for the Grid:

```
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Padding="0,20,0,0">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CommentsMVVM}" HasUnevenRows="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <local:CommentsRow />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

In the CommentsRow template:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="14" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="{ Binding Image }" VerticalOptions="Start" />

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{ Binding UserName }" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Blue" />

    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,4,0,0" Text="{ Binding CreatedAt }" TextColor="Grey" FontSize="13" />

    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Spacing="30" x:Name="StackLayoutMap"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />



</Grid>
```

And at the C#:

```
    public CommentsRow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        var html_label = new HtmlFormattedLabel()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
        };


        html_label.SetBinding(HtmlFormattedLabel.TextProperty, "Memo");

        this.StackLayoutMap.Children.Add(html_label);



    }
```

But the StackLayout comments text just wont expand automatically. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say, it just won't expand?

Comment: Comments section (Row 3 in the picture) wont expand. It will remain in a fix lengt. The Rows won't expand like it should be in the picture.

Comment: Can you do a left vs right on what's happening and what should be happening. I am sorry but it's kind of unclear as to what is the issue here

Comment: Hi @iam.Carrot i am trying but actually its very easy and simple. The Comments section will not show like in the picture. The Rows in the ListView is not showing and expanding like in the picture. It show 1.5 rows. How do i let the XAML do its work when the Rows are like in the Picture. I already use the 'HasUnevenRows="True"' but this also does not do the job! Some comments are like 500 words other are 5 words. So the comments section needs to be like in the Picture :) Thanx for helping!

Comment: Can I see a pictorial representation of what's happening? like a screen grab or something. I know what you need from the image. Now I need to see what's currently happening. or just share a link to a sample project

Comment: Or are you facing a problem in making the think adaptive to the number of lines? Try removing the stacklayout from the listview section and see. I have a silly feeling about this.